# date.getTime is not a function ionic local notification error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, momentjs, localnotification

***Update:***

This is working fine. But could you tell me why this is not working `at: moment(10, "HH")`- with `momentJs`?

```
    let firstNotificationTime = new Date();   
    firstNotificationTime.setDate(firstNotificationTime.getDate());
    firstNotificationTime.setHours(10);
    firstNotificationTime.setMinutes(0);
    firstNotificationTime.setSeconds(0);
    this.localNotifications.schedule({
      id: 1,
      title: 'Due Today',
      text: 'Simons Notification',
      data: { mydata: 'My hidden message this is' },
      at: firstNotificationTime,
     });
  }
```

**Old**

I need to use local notification on Ionic 3 app. I have followed this [**article**](https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-local-notifications/) and below code is working fine. But I need to fire the event at 10.00 AM. So I have tried with `at: moment(10, "HH")`. But it shows this error on the device when running the app.

> Uncaught TypeError: date.getTime is not a function
>       at dateToNum (local-notification-util.js:208)
>       at Object.exports.convertTrigger (local-notification-util.js:234)
>       at Object.exports.convertProperties (local-notification-util.js:156)
>       at Object.fn (local-notification-core.js:75)
>       at local-notification-util.js:326
>       at Object.callbackFromNative (cordova.js:294)
>       at :1:9

This code is working fine. But how to set a time using `moment`?

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
    id: 1,
    title: 'Attention',
    text: 'Simons Notification',
    data: { mydata: 'My hidden message this is' },
    at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 1000)//no issues
    //at: moment(10, "HH")//this shows the above error
  });
```

Comment: *could I have any help to convert it to momentJs*: the documentation provides help. Read it, and try something.

Comment: I did. Maybe you read only the Update section. Could you tell me why this is not working `at: moment(10, "HH")`? @JBNizet

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var theDate = moment(10, HH)


this.localNotifications.schedule({
    id: 1,
    title: 'Attention',
    text: 'Simons Notification',
    data: { mydata: 'My hidden message this is' },
    at: new Date(theDate)
  });
```

Moment.js cannot be use directly in localNotification's plugin. See [documentation](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) to implement date inside localNotification. Hope this may help!